# Una duda con las interfaces en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, interface

Estoy siguiendo un curso sobre Kotlin y he visto algo de las interfaces que no entiendo, a ver si me podéis aclarar la duda. Yo tengo entendido que cuando declaras métodos en una interfaz e implementas dicha interfaz, debes sobreescribir todos estos métodos. Ahora me encuentro en la situación de que en Kotlin se puede crear interfaces con código en sus métodos:

```
interface Toaster {

    val context: Context

    fun toast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Y veo en el siguiente ejemplo que cuando implementa la interfaz lo único que necesita sobreescribir es el atributo context que contiene. ¿Podría alguien explicarme a que es esto debido?

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Toaster {
    override val context = this
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        toast("onCreate")
    }
}
```

Comment: Por lo general se puede decir que las interfaces solo tienen declaraciones de métodos. Pero lo que mencionas de implementar métodos en la interfaz es algo específico del lenguaje.

Comment: @Lobos si, se que esto es algo especifico de Java 8 y de Kotlin pero, porque en este caso solo hay que sobreescribir el context pero no el método toast ?

Comment: La función `toast()` está implementada por eso puede usarse. La variable `context` es abstracta por eso se debe sobreescribir . Puedes revisar la documentación:  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html

Comment: @Lobos con que está implementada te refieres a que se está usando en la clase MyActivity o que en la propia interfaz le está dando un comportamiento?

Comment: A lo segundo. En la interfaz se le agrega un cuerpo a la función por eso puede usarse tal cual sin  necesidad de hacer un override.

Comment: @Lobos es lo que sospechaba, pero no estaba del todo seguro y prefería acudir aquí directamente a ver si me resolvían la duda

Answer (score 0):

En realidad la definiciòn del mètodo en la Interface define que la funcion `toast()` recibe el mensaje a mostrar.

Pero el contexto se define de esta forma ya que debe ser sobreescrito dentro de la Activity, es importante sobreescribirlo ya que [se necesita el context para mostrar un `Toast`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts).

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.Toast

interface Toaster {

    val context: Context

    fun toast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Lo que se realiza es implementar la interface:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Toaster {
```

Lo que se realiza es sobreecribir la funciòn `toast()` ( no el `context`) el cual recibe el mensaje que se mostrarà pero el contexto que se necesita para mostrar este `Toast` lo sobreescribes dentro de la Activity:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Toaster {

    //Sobre escribe el contexto.
    override val context = this

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        //Llama funcion de Interface
        toast("Hola, hoy es un gran dìa!.")

    }
}
```

---

Tambièn puedes definir que la funciòn reciba el contexto:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.Toast

interface Toaster {

    //val context: Context

    fun toast(context: Context, message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

entonces tendrìas que enviar el valor del context y no sobreescribirlo:

```
   class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Toaster {


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

            //Llama funcion de Interface
            toast(this, "Hola, hoy es un gran dìa!.")

        }
    }
```

Comment: Claro, eso lo entiendo. Lo que no me quedaba claro es que como normalmente en una interfaz no se le pone cuerpo a los métodos, cuando implementaba dicha interfaz en la clase tenía que sobreescribir estos métodos que había definido. Aquí en este caso ya le está dando un comportamiento dentro de la interfaz, pero si fuera el método solamente sin cuerpo, si sería obligatorio sobreescribirlo en la clase, ¿no?